# Creating WPF BitmapImage from MemoryStream png, gif

Tags: wpf, image, webrequest, memorystream, bitmapimage

I am having some trouble creating a `BitmapImage` from a `MemoryStream` from png and gif bytes obtained from a web request. The bytes seem to be downloaded fine and the `BitmapImage` object is created without issue however the image is not actually rendering on my UI. The problem only occurs when the downloaded image is of type png or gif (works fine for jpeg).

Here is code that demonstrates the problem:

```
var webResponse = webRequest.GetResponse();
var stream = webResponse.GetResponseStream();
if (stream.CanRead)
{
    Byte[] buffer = new Byte[webResponse.ContentLength];
    stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

    var byteStream = new System.IO.MemoryStream(buffer);

    BitmapImage bi = new BitmapImage();
    bi.BeginInit();
    bi.DecodePixelWidth = 30;
    bi.StreamSource = byteStream;
    bi.EndInit();

    byteStream.Close();
    stream.Close();

    return bi;
}
```

To test that the web request was correctly obtaining the bytes I tried the following which saves the bytes to a file on disk and then loads the image using a `UriSource` rather than a `StreamSource` and it works for all image types:

```
var webResponse = webRequest.GetResponse();
var stream = webResponse.GetResponseStream();
if (stream.CanRead)
{
    Byte[] buffer = new Byte[webResponse.ContentLength];
    stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

    string fName = "c:\\" + ((Uri)value).Segments.Last();
    System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(fName, buffer);

    BitmapImage bi = new BitmapImage();
    bi.BeginInit();
    bi.DecodePixelWidth = 30;
    bi.UriSource = new Uri(fName);
    bi.EndInit();

    stream.Close();

    return bi;
}
```

Anyone got any light to shine?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Add `bi.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad` directly after your `.BeginInit()`:

```
BitmapImage bi = new BitmapImage();
bi.BeginInit();
bi.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
...
```

Without this, BitmapImage uses lazy initialization by default and stream will be closed by then. In first example you try to read image from possibly <strike>garbage-collected</strike> closed or even disposed MemoryStream. Second example uses file, which is still available.
Also, don't write

```
var byteStream = new System.IO.MemoryStream(buffer);
```

better

```
using (MemoryStream byteStream = new MemoryStream(buffer))
{
   ...
}
```

Comment: The `BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad` trick is important. I would just like to add that it should be between `BeginInit()` and `EndInit()`.

Comment: @PieterMüller: Very helpful clue; in addition, the stream still *must* be open when calling `EndInit()` as another constraint that you might stumble over.

Answer (score 14):

I'm using this code:

```
public static BitmapImage GetBitmapImage(byte[] imageBytes)
{
   var bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();
   bitmapImage.BeginInit();
   bitmapImage.StreamSource = new MemoryStream(imageBytes);
   bitmapImage.EndInit();
   return bitmapImage;
}
```

May be you should delete this line:

```
bi.DecodePixelWidth = 30;
```

Comment: But what about closing the memory stream that you created by :
    new MemoryStream(imageBytes)
I think change the CacheOption is better, Should such as streams closed?