# How to convert byte array to uri

Tags: wpf

Have MediaElement in my application used to preview media file such as music, video, image..
MediaElement only allow set source is a URi(contain file path).
I have image storaged by Byte array and now I want preview it on MediaElement.
how to I convert from byte array to uri to preview mediafile ?
If have any other solution to preview mediafie, Please list it. Thank.!

Comment: is it a path in bytes or image itself?

Answer (score 1):

if it is path...then you can use
System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(byteArray[])

and then assign that path to media element to preview image...

If it is image, you have to convert back that image from byte and then assign it ti Image element...to preview. Check this link:
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/ImageConverter.aspx

Comment: Thank for reply. But i want general preview not only image. And I only want display on MediaElement control.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it through a [`MemoryStream`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorystream.aspx). See example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2097152/creating-wpf-bitmapimage-from-memorystream-png-gif/2098165#2098165).

Comment: Thank. May be that is a solution.