# Problem displaying images obtained in byte format from server

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, icons, httpwebresponse, bitmapimage

I am getting a few icon files (92X92) from a server. I need to parse them and store them in a dictionary and later display them on the UI. I am using the following code for obtaining the File Name and for other action:

```
System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage icon = null;
using (AutoResetEvent are = new AutoResetEvent(false))
{
    System.Windows.Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
    {
        MemoryStream byteStream = new MemoryStream(resp);
        byteStream.Write(resp, 0, resp.Length);
        icon = new BitmapImage();
        icon.SetSource(byteStream);
        Console.WriteLine(icon.PixelHeight + ":" + icon.PixelWidth);

        string[] iconname = entry.Name.Split(new char[] { '-' });
        string newimagename = iconname[1];

        are.Set();
        string[] newname = entry.Name.Split(new char[] { '-', '.' });
        iconDict.Add(newimagename, icon);
    });
    are.WaitOne();
    //string[] newname = entry.Name.Split(new char[] { '-', '.' });
    //string newFileName = newname[1];
    //iconDict.Add(newFileName, icon);
}
```

Now my problem is that I am not able to obtain the Uri and am not even getting the icon(but when i put breakpoint n chk the height and width are 92X92); when I try to display it I end up displaying blank space instead of images. I am binding these images to a listbox along with their name that I receive. Names are getting displayed without any problem.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2097152/creating-wpf-bitmapimage-from-memorystream-png-gif, I think it deals with the same issue

Comment: It didnt help, the problem seems similar but i dunno y it is not helping me..

Comment: What format are the images coming over in?  ICO?  BMP?  Other?

Comment: its png format.. the code is working fine  :) am able to see the icons on the UI now :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

changes i made are ;

```
 using (AutoResetEvent are = new AutoResetEvent(false))
 {
  System.Windows.Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
   {
     MemoryStream byteStream = new MemoryStream(resp);
     byteStream.Write(resp, 0, resp.Length);
     string[] iconname = entry.Name.Split(new char[] { '-' });
     string newimagename = iconname[1];

     Uri icon_url = new Uri(newimagename, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
     icon = new BitmapImage(icon_url);
     imag = new Image();
     imag.Source = icon;
     sourceofImage = icon.UriSource.ToString();
     icon.SetSource(byteStream);
     Console.WriteLine(icon.PixelHeight + ":" + icon.PixelWidth);
     are.Set();
     // string[] newname = entry.Name.Split(new char[] { '-', '.' });
    // iconDict.Add(sourceofImage, icon);
    });
    are.WaitOne();
    string[] newname = entry.Name.Split(new char[] { '-', '.' });
    string newFileName = newname[1];
    iconDict.Add(newFileName, icon);
   }
```