# Image.FromStream() in C#

Tags: c#, wpf, image

I work in VS 2010, .Net 4.0.
In Windows forms app, this is ok:

```
Image img = Image.FromStream(imagePart.GetStream());
```

However, in Wpf app, the Image class is from System.Windows.Controls and that isn't valid because it hasn't got a definition for FromStream method.
In Windows forms, the Image class is System.Drawing.Image.

Is there a way I can use FromStream in Wpf app?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2097152/creating-wpf-bitmapimage-from-memorystream-png-gif

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In WPF I *believe* you'd use a [`BitmapSource`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapsource.aspx) such as [`BitmapImage`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapimage.aspx) - and in the latter case, you can set the [`StreamSource`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapimage.streamsource.aspx) property to the appropriate stream.

EDIT: `BitmapSource` is just one subclass of [`ImageSource`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms619185.aspx). Use a source by creating an [`Image`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.image.aspx) control and setting the [`Source`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.image.source.aspx) property.

Comment: An `ImageSource` suffices, which is set as the [`Source`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.image.source.aspx) of the `Image` control.

Comment: @H.B. But for a bitmap, you'd always use a `BitmapSource` of some description, right? Will edit more detail in.

Comment: Yes, i was just reffering to `ImageSource` being the "minimal type".

Comment: @H.B. Righto - see whether my edit captures everything you were trying to help with :)

Comment: Sory, but could you give an example of the code, because I did not understand how to set the `Stream` to `Source`

Comment: @EgoPingvina: I'm not sure what you mean by "set the Stream to Source". You use a StreamSource as the source for your image, passing in the Stream to the StreamSource...