# Creating BitmapImage from a byte array

Tags: c#, wpf, nullpointerexception, memorystream, bitmapimage

I am trying to create a `BitmapImage` from a byte array which is returned by a service.

My code is:

```
using (sc = new ServiceClient())
{
    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(sc.GetImage()))
    {
        Display = new BitmapImage();
        Display.BeginInit();
        Display.StreamSource = ms;
        Display.EndInit();
    }
}
```

However, an exception is thrown at the `EndInit` method. It says `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`.

It seems, that Uri is null and it causes the problem. Unfortunately, I cannot find a solution myself.

Comment: According to the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapimage.streamsource.aspx), do you also assign a value to `Display.UriSource`? If so, it will ignore the `StreamSource`. In addition, do you have the `CacheOption` property set to `BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad`? EDIT: Also, it appears that `Display` is a member (field/property), is it possible you have a threading issue here that replaces/changes `Display` as you're working with it?

Comment: @ChrisSinclair, I do not assign a vaule to UriSource. I just checked a stack trace and it seemed to me, that a null pointer exception is thrown due to this attribute. It was just a guess. Display is a property indeed, which is bound to my XAML layout. So, basically I would like to get an image from the WCF service and then display it at the WPF window. Besides this binding, I do not have code, which can cause a threading issue.

Comment: Can you try setting its `CacheOption` property to `BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad`? Otherwise, from what I understand, it will lazily try to access the stream which may be closed by the time it reads it. According to comments [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2250851/1269654) be sure to set it after `BeginInit()`. EDIT: that is: `Display = new BitmapImage(); Display.BeginInit(); Display.CacheMode = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad; Display.StreamSource = ms; Display.EndInit();`

Comment: @ChrisSinclair, BitmapImage does not have CacheMode property, I suppose you are reffering to CacheOption one instead. Unfortunately, adding this line did not help. I still have a null pointer exception...

Comment: Yeah, it was a typo, sorry. Glad you managed to figure out the problem!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, it turned out, that WPF binding was causing the error.

```
private BitmapImage _display;
public BitmapImage Display
{
    get { return _display; }
    set
    {
        _display = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged("Display");
    }
}
```

I resolved the issue by getting an image not in the property Display itself, but rather in the filed _display. So, the following is working fine.

```
using (sc = new ServiceClient())
{
    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(sc.GetImage()))
    {
        _display = new BitmapImage();
        _display.BeginInit();
        _display.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
        _display.StreamSource = ms;
        _display.EndInit();
    }
}

Display = _display;
```

Answer (score 1):

u are assigning `memory stream` directly to the `bitmap` `source`, which causes `error`.
first u need to get that `array` of `bytes` & than `convert` it into the `memory stream` and then assign to the `bitmap source`, that's it !!!

```
using (sc = new ServiceClient())
    {
            Byte[] array = sc.GetImage();

            Display = new BitmapImage();
            Display.BeginInit();
            Display.StreamSource = new MemoryStream(array);
            Display.EndInit();
     }
```

Comment: I didn't know you could have `using` on a `byte[]`; I thought it _must_ be `IDisposable`. EDIT: Quick test, I don't think you can. How is this code (assuming you fix it) any different than what's supplied? It just avoids disposing the stream?

Comment: The description in your updated answer is _exactly_ what Dmitry is already doing. The _only_ difference between your answer and his original code is that your answer doesn't dispose the memory stream.

Comment: Well, as @ChrisSinclair said, your code causes the same behaviour as one in my question with the only difference: in your case the memory stream stays in the memory forever. Unfortunately, the same exception is thrown.