# How do i retrieve image from database in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf

i have a hard time from switching from winform to wpf... in winform i just easily read image using picturebox.image

`byte[] imgg = (byte[])(reader["profilepic"]);
                    MemoryStream mstream = new MemoryStream(imgg);
                    pic1.Image = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(mstream);`

but in wpf picture box is not available instead an image so i tried the same code just incase it would work

```
void readName()
    {          
        try
        {
            MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(myConnection);
            conn.Open();
            MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand("SELECT profilepic FROM maindatabase.users where user=?parameter1;", conn);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("?parameter1", UserList.SelectedItem.ToString());
            MySqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

            //int ctr = 0;
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                //ctr++;
                byte[] imgg = (byte[])(reader["profilepic"]);
               MemoryStream mstream = new MemoryStream(imgg);
               pic1 = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(mstream);
               //but got an error since system.drawing cant convert system.windows.control.image

               //and after looking in the internet just tried this code but it doesnt seems to work too
                if (imgg != null)
                {
                    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(imgg))
                    {
                        // Load the image from the memory stream. How you do it depends
                        // on whether you're using Windows Forms or WPF.
                        // For Windows Forms you could write:
                        // System.Drawing.Bitmap bmp = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(ms);
                        imgPic1 = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(ms);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("null");
                }



            }
        }
        catch 
        {
           // MessageBox.Show("error" + ex);

        }

    }
```

xaml code

```
<Border BorderThickness="1"
    BorderBrush="#FF000000"
    VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="10,19,158,33" Height="128">
        <Image Name="pic1"
       Height="128"
       Stretch="Fill"
       VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="48,-1,39,-1" Width="128"/>
    </Border>
```

i know winforms and wpf are different so i'll admit that i'm really noob at wpf so if someone can help me..thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WPF does not support Bitmap from `System.Drawing` namespace.
Use some kind of `ImageSource` like `BitmapImage` or `BitmapSource`!

[Creating WPF BitmapImage from MemoryStream png, gif](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2097152/creating-wpf-bitmapimage-from-memorystream-png-gif)

And set this object as `Source` of `Image`

Comment: tnx for the tips just got codes from here  https://codezone4.wordpress.com/2012/06/24/save-and-retrieve-images-in-wpf-from-database/

Answer (score 0):

```
           var veri = SirketBilgileriData.SirketBilgiListele(); 
           if (veri.SingleOrDefault().Logo == null) { logo.Source =null; } else {
                byte[] kayitliLogo = (byte[])veri.SingleOrDefault().Logo;
                MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(kayitliLogo);
                var resimKaynak = new BitmapImage();
                resimKaynak.BeginInit();
                resimKaynak.StreamSource = ms;
                resimKaynak.EndInit();
                logo.Source = resimKaynak;
            }
```