# 'BitmapImage' does not contain a definition for 'SetSource' and no accessible extension method 'SetSource'

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm trying to use the method SetSource in my converter to convert a byte array to BitmapImage, but unfortunately the method looks gone.

I checked the documentation and the method is still in use.
Link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/cc189859(v=vs.95)

Any Ideas ?

```
public static BitmapImage ConvertByteArrayToBitMapImage(byte[] imageByteArray)
    {
        BitmapImage img = new BitmapImage();
        using (MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream(imageByteArray))
        {
            img.SetSource(memStream);
        }
        return img;
    }
```

Comment: This method is from Silverlight and is indeed dead. Instead, look at the following question: [Creating WPF BitmapImage from MemoryStream png, gif](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2097152/creating-wpf-bitmapimage-from-memorystream-png-gif)

Comment: There is still a SetSource method in the UWP/WinUI BitmapImage, but you would prefer SetSourceAsync there.

Answer (score 0):

I have to signal the start and end of the initialization of the BitmapImage, and also set `BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad` when the stream is closed after EndInit.

```
using (MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream(imageByteArray))
{ 
    img.BeginInit();
    img.StreamSource = memStream;
    img.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
    img.EndInit();
}
```